# homomorphism between the automorphism group of $G$ and $G/H$ for a characteristic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove that if $H \leq G$ is characteristic, then there exists a homomorphism between $Aut(G) → Aut(G/H)$ given by $\phi \rightarrow \bar \phi$ where $\bar \phi(gH) = \phi(g)H$.

Clearly H is normal in this case, so $G/H$ and by extension $Aut(G/H)$ is well-defined. All that remains to show, I believe, is that the mapping is homomorphic, i.e: $\bar \phi_1(gH) \circ \bar \phi_2(gH) = (\bar \phi_1 \circ \bar \phi_2) (gH)$.

We have that $\bar \phi_1(gH) \circ \bar \phi_2(gH) = \phi_1(g)H \circ \phi_2(g)H$. Whenever $g \in H$, then everything works out trivially as H is characteristic. When $g \notin H$, I'm not exactly sure to harness characteristicness.

Comment: You seem to be multiplying $\overline{\phi_1}(gH)\in G/H$ and $\overline{\phi_2}(gH)\in G/H$ using the group operation in $G/H$. This would be denoted $\overline{\phi_1}(gH)\overline{\phi_2}(gH)$, not $\overline{\phi_1}(gH)\circ \overline{\phi_2}(gH)$. In any case, checking that $\phi\mapsto\overline{\phi}$ is a homomorphism does not involve multiplying in $G/H$.

Comment: Oh yep, sorry. Forgot the circ. Should be fixed.

Comment: You didn't forget any circ. I'm telling you there **shouldn't be a circ** in the expression $$ \overline{\phi_1}(gH)\circ\overline{\phi_2}(gH). $$ The above expression is nonsensical, it doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 4):

The operation in $\mathrm{Aut}(G/H)$ is function composition, not pointwise multiplication, so the condition that it is a homomorphism should actually read

$$(\overline{\phi_1\circ \phi_2})=\overline{\phi_1}\circ \overline{\phi_2}, $$

$$\iff \overline{\phi_1\circ \phi_2}(gH)=\overline{\phi_1}(\overline{\phi_2}(gH)) $$

$$\iff (\phi_1\circ \phi_2)(g)H=\overline{\phi_1}(\phi_2(g)H) $$

$$\iff \phi_1(\phi_2(g))H=\phi_1(\phi_2(g))H, $$

which is clearly true.

What you haven't used is the fact that $H$ is a characteristic subgroup. This is important: it's necessary to use this fact to show that $\overline{\phi}(gH)=\phi(g)H$ even makes sense so that $\overline{\phi}$ is well-defined.

To do this, you will need to show that

$$ g_1H=g_2H ~\implies~ \phi(g_1)H=\phi(g_2)H.$$

(If this implication didn't hold, do you see why $\overline{gH}:=\phi(g)H$ wouldn't make sense as a definition?)

I'll let you try your hand at proving this implication.

Comment: For the last part, it looks like we're trying to get at something like $ \phi (g_1) \phi(H) = \phi(g_2) \phi(H)$ where characteristicness of $H$ ensures the desired result. Presumably, though, we can't just extend $\phi$ over a coset $gH$ and then unpack it as a product ... can we?

Comment: @cloudchamber You have the correct intuition: $\overline{\phi}(gH)$ is essentially just $\phi(gH)$, which equals $\phi(g)\phi(H)$, which equals $\phi(g)H$.